# Do I always have to declare any method that doesn't affect instance state, as const?

Tags: c++, class, constants

I have a class with the following method:

```
int getLength() {
    return length;
}
```

(The class is called `String`, I'm defining it for practice).

When I tried to compile, I got an error regarding a line of code that calls this method:

```
passing 'const String' as 'this' argument of int String::getLength() discards qualifiers.
```

A search on this site made me realize I needed to add `const` in the method declaration. It fixed the problem.

My question:

Do I always have to declare any method that doesn't affect instance state, as `const`? And if I don't, I get a compile time error? Seems very odd.

If I don't have to do this always, than what are the situation when I do have to declare the method as `const`?

Comment: If you post an error message, it would be a good idea to also post the source line (+context) to which the error message refers.. as you already say yourself, the error does not occur because you *declare* the method as non-const, but because you *use* it on a non-const object/reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler error is not caused by the method, but by the type of the instance you are calling it on. You try to call a non-const method on a const object (`const String`) or reference to const object (`const String&`). This is rightfully rejected by the compiler.

And, yes, you should mark all methods which are logically `const` as `const`.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Indeed I was calling this method on a `const String&` object. Thanks

Comment: @AvivCohn: that statement isn't correct. Objects are never references. You were calling the methond on a value (specifcally, an lvalue) of type `const String`, presumably obtained by evaluating a reference variable, or perhaps on an rvalue.